# Externalise Log4j2.xml file in Mule 4 APIs via Spring Beans

Tags: mule, log4j2, mulesoft, mule4

We have a specific requirement to load log4j2.xml file from external location rather than classpath. I've tried below approaches:

1. **mule_artifact.json**: Specifying "logConfigFile" in this json works but the problem is that it has to be absolute path. Unfortunately, we have different paths in different servers. Don't thin it supports property placeholders or system properties inside this property.
2. **beans.xml**: Initialising beans.xml with log4j file as below and importing using spring module. This is not working any more as I read **org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer** is not supported anymore. If supported, can I get working example in **Mule 4.3.0**?

```
<spring:bean id="log4jInitialization"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
            <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
            <spring:property name="arguments">
                <spring:list>
                    <spring:value>classpath:log4j/${log4j.properties.location}</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

3. **log4j.configurationFile**: Can't use this property as all APIs should have their own config.

I'm exhausted and not finding a way to load external log4j2.xml file dynamically.

Please suggest.

Comment: @aled -  The second option worked like a charm. Not sure how I missed that.. THANK YOU for pointing me to right article.

Comment: You'll need to test it for Mule 4.

Comment: I had to slightly change it for Mule 4 but working fine. I voted the original answer. Not sure if I need to post the modified answer here as I specifically asked for mule 4 and original post was for Mule 3 albeit 80% same solution.